# Convergence in probability, infinite product of sigma algebras

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

In page 272 of Billingsley (ex. 20.24 (a)) it says:

"Show that in a discrete probability space convergence in probabil­ity is equivalent to convergence with probability 1"

If we consider a countable infinite product of discrete probability spaces, is the same result still true for the product measure?

Comment: This statement is not true for infinite product of discrete probability spaces.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the counterexample about it?

Comment: How do you define the convergence in probability in this context?

Comment: A countable infinite product of discrete probability spaces is a probability space, but it is **not** a discrete probability space.